# Pytest mock when using multiprocessing: How to wait until method is called?

Tags: python, pytest, python-multiprocessing, pytest-mock

I would like to test the following code using pytest and [pytest-mock](https://pytest-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) (this is a minimal example from a larger program):

```
import logging
import multiprocessing
import os

def task():
    logging.info('task started')
    os.execvp('gedit', ['gedit', '/tmp/foo.txt'])
 
def main():
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=task, daemon=False)
    process.start()

def test_main(mocker):
    mock = mocker.MagicMock()
    mocker.patch(__name__ + ".os.execvp", mock)
    main()
    assert mock.called

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    main()
```

Current output from running `pytest t.py` is:

```
>       assert mock.called
E       AssertionError: assert False
E        +  where False = <MagicMock id='139999769857040'>.called

t.py:21: AssertionError
```

I suspect this is because the `assert mock.called` is called before the mock has been called in the separate process. What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Your mock object isn't going to be shared across processes

Answer (score 2):

Intentionally or not, your `main` method does not call `process.join()`.  So your `main` returns as soon as it starts the task.  `main` returns, you check `mock.called`, and you've got a classic race condition.

If your intent was for `main` to wait for the task to finish, then add the `process.join()`.  If not, you can have `main()` return `process`.  In most cases, this value is ignored, but it's available for your test so that it can wait for `task` to finish.

---

Addressing your question.  You are absolutely correct.  I only saw half the problem.

One fix would be to patch `os.execvp` to be a function that ignores its argument and increments a shared variable.

An alternative fix is to use a packe like [SharedMock](https://python-sharedmock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that understands multiprocessing.

Comment: Thanks for this info! It does not work still, I think it is because the mock object is modified in a different process? So the mock object in the test process is not modified. Maybe we need to use `multiprocessing.Queue` or something similar to communicate?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using `multiprocessing.Queue` to communicate:

```
import logging
import multiprocessing
import os

def orig_task(*args):
    logging.info('task started')
    os.execvp('gedit', ['gedit', '/tmp/foo.txt'])

def main(task=orig_task, queue=None):
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=task, daemon=False, args=(queue,))
    process.start()

def test_main(mocker):
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    def gen_wrapper():
        def wrapper(queue, *args, **kwargs):
            execvp_args = None
            def execvp_mock(*args, **kwargs):
                nonlocal execvp_args
                execvp_args = [*args]
            os.execvp = execvp_mock
            orig_task(queue, *args, **kwargs)
            queue.put(execvp_args)
        return wrapper
    wrapper = gen_wrapper()
    main(wrapper, q)
    execvp_args = q.get()
    assert execvp_args[0] == 'gedit'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    main()
```

Or better, using `unittest.mock` to automatically restore the mocked method:

```
def test_main(mocker):
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    def gen_wrapper():
        def wrapper(queue, *args, **kwargs):
            with unittest.mock.patch.object(os, "execvp") as mock:
                orig_task(queue, *args, **kwargs)
            queue.put(mock.call_args.args)
        return wrapper
    wrapper = gen_wrapper()
    main(wrapper, q)
    execvp_args = q.get()
    assert execvp_args[0] == 'gedit'
```